# Collecting results from a Asynchronously triggered process

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am triggering a process asynchronously using Process.Start(). I am then waiting  for it to complete using Process.WaitForExit(). Things are good till here. But I want the completed process to send back a custom object to the caller on completion. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

No. No 'object' can belong to a zombie process.

If you want IPC (Inter Process Communication), you must do it while the process is alive. You have plenty of choices for the technology (shared memory, named pipes, COM, RPC, LRPC, HTTP, WCF etc etc etc), but (almost) *all* require for the process to be alive.

You may want to consider a **file** instead. The child process writes to a file then terminates, then the parent process reads the file. This is fairly standard.

The one IPC exception is queued communication. This requires you to use some queuing technology. Read about [Message Queuing (MSMQ)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms711472%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks Remus. What you say makes sense. In that case, can it work this way? The new process sends the object back to the caller and then terminates. But the caller SHOULD WAIT TILL IT RECEIVES THE OUTPUT. I was going through Process.OutputDataReceived Event. Will the caller wait if this handler is used? Or is there any other way?

Comment: It depends a lot by what do you mean by 'the process sends the object'

Comment: The object will contain some status and information about the processing. Number of lines processed, End Time, etc. The caller needs to know this information.

Comment: You don't understand. There are no 'objects'. This is not C#. This is the OS. Processes. What **IPC** technology are you going to use? You have to answer something like "a file" or "stdin" or "COM" or "RPC".

Comment: Hey Remus, when you said file in your last comment, I thought if a file stream could be sent; so asked about XML. But I guess you were referring to the child process writing to a file, right?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it using the below code. The Standard Output of the newProcess will be captured in the caller after newProcess terminates.

```
newProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "Auto_Process2.exe";
newProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
newProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

if (newProcess.Start())
{
  while (!newProcess.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
  {
     newProcessOutput = newProcess.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
  }
}
```